# Fee JPA compatible Object Database

Tags: database, jpa, objectdb

I develop JSF web applications using JPA to manage databases.

I use EclipseLink with MySQL frequently in all most all web applications.

I have used ObjecDb (with the restricted licence) with JPA. It is very fast when compared to MySQL + EclipseLink. ObjectDB works very nicely with JPA as well.

But my issue is that I can not afford the ObjectDB licence as I am from a developing country where majority spend only 0.7 USD for a Lunch on average. (ObjectDB licence is £300  for a single server and  £1,800 for site licence at this moment.)

I want to know is there any Object database which is compatible with JPA with an open source licence?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are both free, and fast databases. JPA (of which EclipseLink is an implementation) is a spec to persist Java objects in relational databases, so a relational database is the natural choice if you use JPA. If it isn't fast enough, it's most certainly because of your code, or of a configuration or hardware problem, and not because of the underlying database. You should show an example of slow code, tell us how much time it takes, and ask us why it's slow.